# Can I use zero in a column which has the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I'm using a MySQL 5.0 server. My requirement is to add one special row to an existing table which has an auto-increment primary key.

It would be very useful for future maintenance and management of the project if we were able to make the id of this row 0 (because it's easy to remember and easy to spot in manual observations).

Now, I know that MySQL has no problem with you using your own value for an autoincrement column, and my tests have shown that I can set the autoincrement primary key of a row to 0 with an UPDATE query. However, some concerns have been raised about how this might affect the auto-increment functionality of the column in future INSERTs.

My (limited) experiments have shown nothing strange and I can't find anything specific warning against this in the MySQL docs. That is, apart from this (emphasis mine): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html

> There can be only one AUTO_INCREMENT column per table, it must be indexed, and it cannot have a DEFAULT value. An AUTO_INCREMENT column works properly only if it contains only positive values. Inserting a negative number is regarded as inserting a very large positive number. **This is done to avoid precision problems when numbers “wrap” over from positive to negative and also to ensure that you do not accidentally get an AUTO_INCREMENT column that contains 0.**

I am unable to find an explanation for what is wrong with having a value of zero in an AUTO_INCREMENT column, so can anyone tell me if having an AUTO_INCREMENT column that contains 0 is a bad thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have already discovered, it's not possible to asign a 0  to an auto increment field with an INSERT, you need to use an UPDATE. AFAIK there is nothing wrong with having a 0 in a row except when you try to dump and import. But that can be avoided by first inserting the data and then later marking it as an auto increment field.

Comment: Good call on a reimport. I hadn't considered that as we don't do that often, but we'll make note of that in case we do.

As far as I know there's nothing wrong with 0 in a auto increment column either :).
But that note I quoted suggests otherwise, so I was hoping to get an answer that either explains why the reference manual says that, or why it might be wrong.

How confident are you be that there is nothing wrong with 0 in an auto increment column?

Comment: I am pretty confident that you will be alright. This one time i did have a 0 in an autoincrement field due to a bug in my code, it didn't have any adverse side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Storing 0 is not a recommended practice. For example, if you dump the table with `mysqldump` and then reload it, MySQL normally generates new sequence numbers when it encounters the 0 values, resulting in a table with contents different from the one that was dumped. Enabling [NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero) before reloading the dump file solves this problem. `mysqldump` now automatically includes in its output a statement that enables `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO`, to avoid this problem.